# why stimulsoft reports js clustered chart y axis format not getting set

Tags: stimulsoft, stimulusjs

hi i am new to stimulsoft, i am using stimulsoft report js to  generate a report, but i am not able to set my Y-axis format.

i tried using N2 but instead of showing numbers in y-axis its starts showing N2. One more problem is that data on each bar is showing some random numbers though in tool tip its showing correct value of each bar.
[image]

[image]

My JSON data is something like this and in stimulsoft i made a relationship between marks and studdet inside marks.

```
[{
"studdet":[

{"Admnno":"18","stdnm":"NIKITA BERA","fname":"NIRMAL BERA","mname":"CHINU BERA","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"9","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"63","stdnm":"ANIMESH KUMAR PRASWANI","fname":"PRADUMAN PASWAN","mname":"SUNILA DEVI","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"10","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"33","stdnm":"VISHAL KUMAR","fname":"DILIP KUMAR","mname":"SUMAN DEVI","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"11","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"54","stdnm":"ANIKET PANDEY","fname":"NAND KUMAR PANDEY","mname":"NITU DEVI PANDEY","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"12","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"9","stdnm":"NIGAM KUMAR","fname":"BRIJESH KUMAR RAY","mname":"PAMMY DEVI","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"13","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"55","stdnm":"RAJ KUMAR","fname":"RAGHVENDRA PRASAD","mname":"SANJU DEVI","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"14","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"23","stdnm":"SHUBHAM DEY","fname":"DIPAK DEY","mname":"PUMPA DEY","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"15","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"34","stdnm":"JIBESH GHOSH","fname":"SUSHANTA KUMAR GHOSH","mname":"LATIKA GHOSH","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"16","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"Admnno":"45","stdnm":"SHRUTI AGARWAL","fname":"SANJAY KUMAR AGARWAL","mname":"SIMA DEVI","add":"JAMSHEDPUR ","cls":"I","sec":"A","roll":"17","dob":"2019-04-16","session":"2019","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
],

"marks":[
{"fullPt1":20,"marksObtPt1":10,"wtPt1":10,"fullMarksPt1":20,"UT1":5,"examNamePt1":"ut1","fullCt1":10,"marksObtCt1":10,"wtCt1":10,"fullMarksCt1":10,"calculatedCt1":10,"examNameCt1":"ct1","fullPt3":10,"marksObtPt3":5,"wtPt3":10,"fullMarksPt3":10,"calculatedPt3":5,"examNamePt3":"pt3","fullUt2":0,"marksObtUt2":0,"wtUt2":0,"fullMarksUt2":0,"calculatedUt2":0,"examNameUt2":0,"fullCt2":0,"marksObtCt2":0,"wtCt2":0,"fullMarksCt2":0,"calculatedCt2":0,"examNameCt2":0,"fullPt6":0,"marksObtPt6":0,"wtPt6":0,"fullMarksPt6":0,"calculatedPt6":0,"examNamePt6":0,"fullNb1":5,"marksObtNb1":2,"wtNb1":5,"fullMarksNb1":5,"nb":2,"examNameNb1":"nb1","fullSe1":5,"marksObtSe1":3,"wtSe1":5,"fullMarksSe1":5,"se":3,"examNameSe1":"se1","fullHf":80,"marksObtHf":10,"wtHf":80,"fullMarksHf":80,"hf":10,"examNameHf":"hf","fullPortf":5,"marksObtPortf":1,"wtPortf":10,"fullMarksPortf":5,"calculatedPortf":2,"examNamePortf":"PORTF1","subjectCodeCom":"1","PaperName":"Mathematics","Admnno":"18","typeCom":"Main","selectedCom":true,"total":32,"examName":"Periodic Test (10)","highestMarks":"80","grade":"E","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"fullPt1":20,"marksObtPt1":10,"wtPt1":10,"fullMarksPt1":20,"UT1":5,"examNamePt1":"ut1","fullCt1":10,"marksObtCt1":5,"wtCt1":10,"fullMarksCt1":10,"calculatedCt1":5,"examNameCt1":"ct1","fullPt3":10,"marksObtPt3":5,"wtPt3":10,"fullMarksPt3":10,"calculatedPt3":5,"examNamePt3":"pt3","fullUt2":0,"marksObtUt2":0,"wtUt2":0,"fullMarksUt2":0,"calculatedUt2":0,"examNameUt2":0,"fullCt2":0,"marksObtCt2":0,"wtCt2":0,"fullMarksCt2":0,"calculatedCt2":0,"examNameCt2":0,"fullPt6":0,"marksObtPt6":0,"wtPt6":0,"fullMarksPt6":0,"calculatedPt6":0,"examNamePt6":0,"fullNb1":5,"marksObtNb1":2,"wtNb1":5,"fullMarksNb1":5,"nb":2,"examNameNb1":"nb1","fullSe1":5,"marksObtSe1":3,"wtSe1":5,"fullMarksSe1":5,"se":3,"examNameSe1":"se1","fullHf":80,"marksObtHf":5,"wtHf":80,"fullMarksHf":80,"hf":5,"examNameHf":"hf","fullPortf":5,"marksObtPortf":1,"wtPortf":10,"fullMarksPortf":5,"calculatedPortf":2,"examNamePortf":"PORTF1","subjectCodeCom":"2","PaperName":"English","Admnno":"18","typeCom":"Main","selectedCom":true,"total":22,"examName":"Periodic Test (10)","highestMarks":"80","grade":"E","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"fullPt1":20,"marksObtPt1":10,"wtPt1":10,"fullMarksPt1":20,"UT1":5,"examNamePt1":"ut1","fullCt1":10,"marksObtCt1":5,"wtCt1":10,"fullMarksCt1":10,"calculatedCt1":5,"examNameCt1":"ct1","fullPt3":10,"marksObtPt3":5,"wtPt3":10,"fullMarksPt3":10,"calculatedPt3":5,"examNamePt3":"pt3","fullUt2":0,"marksObtUt2":0,"wtUt2":0,"fullMarksUt2":0,"calculatedUt2":0,"examNameUt2":0,"fullCt2":0,"marksObtCt2":0,"wtCt2":0,"fullMarksCt2":0,"calculatedCt2":0,"examNameCt2":0,"fullPt6":0,"marksObtPt6":0,"wtPt6":0,"fullMarksPt6":0,"calculatedPt6":0,"examNamePt6":0,"fullNb1":5,"marksObtNb1":2,"wtNb1":5,"fullMarksNb1":5,"nb":2,"examNameNb1":"nb1","fullSe1":5,"marksObtSe1":3,"wtSe1":5,"fullMarksSe1":5,"se":3,"examNameSe1":"se1","fullHf":80,"marksObtHf":6,"wtHf":80,"fullMarksHf":80,"hf":6,"examNameHf":"hf","fullPortf":5,"marksObtPortf":1,"wtPortf":10,"fullMarksPortf":5,"calculatedPortf":2,"examNamePortf":"PORTF1","subjectCodeCom":"3","PaperName":"Hindi","Admnno":"18","typeCom":"Main","selectedCom":true,"total":23,"examName":"Periodic Test (10)","highestMarks":"80","grade":"E","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},
{"fullPt1":20,"marksObtPt1":10,"wtPt1":10,"fullMarksPt1":20,"UT1":5,"examNamePt1":"ut1","fullCt1":10,"marksObtCt1":5,"wtCt1":10,"fullMarksCt1":10,"calculatedCt1":5,"examNameCt1":"ct1","fullPt3":10,"marksObtPt3":5,"wtPt3":10,"fullMarksPt3":10,"calculatedPt3":5,"examNamePt3":"pt3","fullUt2":0,"marksObtUt2":0,"wtUt2":0,"fullMarksUt2":0,"calculatedUt2":0,"examNameUt2":0,"fullCt2":0,"marksObtCt2":0,"wtCt2":0,"fullMarksCt2":0,"calculatedCt2":0,"examNameCt2":0,"fullPt6":0,"marksObtPt6":0,"wtPt6":0,"fullMarksPt6":0,"calculatedPt6":0,"examNamePt6":0,"fullNb1":5,"marksObtNb1":2,"wtNb1":5,"fullMarksNb1":5,"nb":2,"examNameNb1":"nb1","fullSe1":5,"marksObtSe1":3,"wtSe1":5,"fullMarksSe1":5,"se":3,"examNameSe1":"se1","fullHf":80,"marksObtHf":9,"wtHf":80,"fullMarksHf":80,"hf":9,"examNameHf":"hf","fullPortf":5,"marksObtPortf":1,"wtPortf":10,"fullMarksPortf":5,"calculatedPortf":2,"examNamePortf":"PORTF1","subjectCodeCom":"4","PaperName":"Physics","Admnno":"18","typeCom":"Main","selectedCom":true,"total":26,"examName":"Periodic Test (10)","highestMarks":"80","grade":"E","attworking":"0","attpresent":"0"},],}]
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using older version of stimulsoft which was 2018.3.3 and when i updated my version to 2019.3.4 my problem was resolved